# Path of Exile map signs

Tags: path-of-exile

I recently started playing path of exile and I'm confused with the main map signs. What is the blue dot, the blue circle, the yellow sign and all the others?

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are asking about the [world](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/The_World) map, not the [end-game maps](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Map).

From [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/102606/15726):

- blue points = areas with activated portals
- blue circles = areas with unfound portals

Also:

- circle with a question mark = unvisited area
- green character = current location (kinda obvious)
- pathes and locations highlighted in yellow/gold = path to the currently selected quest